# How to use if statement right (javascript)

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I got this code that works perfectly fine, just like i want it to, but then i want to extend it with else if, but the way i have done my code, that's not possible. Feel free to link some good site to learn from.

```
if(wallLeft < marioLeft && wallLeftWidth > marioLeft)
{    

}
else
{
    newLeft = marioLeft - 5;
    mario.style.left = newLeft + "px";
}

//else if(wallLeftWidth < marioLeft && wallLeftWidth > marioLeftWidth)
{   }
else
{ //some code }
```

Comment: `else-if` should come before `else`

Comment: writing with formatting like: if(something){}else{ makes code look terrible.

Comment: Why do keep reversing the statements, just swap the operators instead

Comment: `else { .....` statement should be at last...

Comment: The syntax is `if...else if...else`. You can have as many `else if` as you want, but there can only be one `else` statement at the very end. There are JavaScript reference guides where you can read about the basic syntax: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inverse your conditions, writing `if(...){}else{...}` looks horrible and is really bad practice. Additionally the order is `if`, `else if`, `else`, you cant use `else if` after `else`.

```
if( wallLeft > marioLeft || wallLeftWidth < marioLeft ) {
    newLeft = marioLeft - 5;
    mario.style.left = newLeft + "px";
} else if( wallLeftWidth > marioLeft || wallLeftWidth < marioLeftWidth) {
    //some code 
}
```

Comment: That works nice! will accept your answer when i can, (6 minutes)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is wrong. Try this;

```
if (wallLeft < marioLeft && wallLeftWidth > marioLeft) {
    newLeft = marioLeft - 5;
    mario.style.left = newLeft + "px";
} else if (wallLeftWidth < marioLeft && wallLeftWidth > marioLeftWidth) { 
    //some code 
}
```

Comment: But the code inside the first if-statement i only want to call when the if is false

Comment: If it is false, it does not enter in first if statement