# if statement cant apply the operator '<=' at the operators of type 'bool' and 'float'

Tags: c#

```
bool isMouseClicked;
bool Test;
float Number1;
float Number2;
float Number3;

isMouseClicked = true;
Number1 = -1;
Number2 = 0;
Number3 = 1; 

void Update()
{
   if (isMouseClicked && Number1 <= Number2 <= Number3)
   {
      Test = true;
   }
}
```

When I run this program it tells me `Operator '<=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'bool' and 'float'`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use if statement right (javascript)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21221945/how-to-use-if-statement-right-javascript)

Comment: Change it to: `Number1 <= Number2  && Number2 <= Number3`

Answer (score 5):

This:

```
Number1 <= Number2 <= Number3
```

Means this:

```
(Number1 <= Number2) <= Number3
```

And a number can not be greater than or less than a boolean value.

Basically, you're thinking about this in terms of intuitive human languages.  Don't.  Think about this in terms of logical conditions.  What are the conditions you want to express?

You want to express this:

```
Number1 <= Number2
```

And this:

```
Number2 <= Number3
```

The language used says it all... "this **and** this".  Combine the operations exactly like that:

```
Number1 <= Number2 && Number2 <= Number3
```

So overall each logical operation is its own distinct condition being checked:

```
if (
  isMouseClicked
  && Number1 <= Number2
  && Number2 <= Number3
)
```

Comment: yeah, i just yought that you could do a double check thanks